# How can Web Developers take advantage of Google's Public DNS

Tags: web-applications, dns

Google recently announced their [Public DNS Service](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/intro.html). It's suppose to be faster and more secure than regular DNS.

Based on the Google instructions and my limited understanding of DNS it can only be used by web surfers.

How can web developers take advantage of Google's new service to better our websites and web applications?

Is their any drawback/disadvantage to web developers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not really anything for web developers to take advantage of; however, server and network administrators now have the option of another free DNS provider.

Answer (score 11):

Which DNS server a visitor uses makes no difference to the web developer.

Comment: +1. All the DNS does is takes a domain name and points it to the IP. It only affects the user as that resolution of domain to IP might be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.  If you find it better/faster/stronger, recommend it to your friends and colleagues.  That's about it.